# How to check if an array contains a partial value once?

Tags: java

I have an array,

```
arr = [name1 class age, name2 class age, name3 class age, name1 class age, name2 class age]
```

I want to check each item and store it in another array

```
String[] r = Arrays.stream(arr)
    .filter(s -> s.contains("name1"))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

How do I save just the first name1 using the above code?

output: `[name1 class age, name1 class age]`

expected output: `[name1 class age]`

Comment: what's not working here? Post a [mcve]

Comment: @Reimeus Please check the updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to retrieve only the first found element:

```
String[] r = new String[] { Arrays.stream(arr)
                                  .filter(s -> s.contains("name1"))
                                  .findFirst().orElse("") };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the first match

```
String[] array = 
  Arrays.stream(arr).filter
  (s -> s.contains("name1")).findFirst().map(s -> new String[] { s }).orElse(new String[] {});
```